# TypeScript doesn't understand the return type of a `filter` on an array

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following:

```
const data = [
    { id: '1' },
    { id: null },
    { id: '2' },
    { id: null },
    { id: '3' },
];

const result: string[] = data.map(({ id }) => id).filter(Boolean);
      ^^^^^^
// Type '(string | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
```

I know I can add `as string[]` at the end, but why is this happening, if the result of such an operation will obviously never yield an array with a `null` element in it?

Comment: Because the return type of `Boolean` is _just a boolean_, not a type predicate - TypeScript doesn't know what you _mean_ by it. `.filter((value): value is string => Boolean(value))` would work, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is not smart enough to understand what Boolean might be doing. It is doing strict checking, by looking at the possible types that can be returned from `filter()` method which is `(string | null)[]`

If you use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) it will work:

```
const data = [
    { id: '1' },
    { id: null },
    { id: '2' },
    { id: null },
    { id: '3' },
];

const result: string[] = data.map(({ id }) => id).filter((id) : id is string => Boolean(id));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeMAlnAFwwDkAjBTAL4A0OehJ5YArgDZf1N4FiZSgCZajZrlbDOPPpMFtKAZnFMAugG4sWUJFgAnAKYRuUctANEwAcwzq08JAgB0AWwQAHABTfp9AEo0AD4hAJcAMyIuKCMDXxIg8hJiCBhLaxsQmAAhEBAuIwQwb0SAzSA)